# How to sort images by aspect ratio

Tags: shell, sorting, awk, sed, exiftool

I want to sort images by aspect ratio, then use [MPV](https://mpv.io) to browse them, and I got some codes from Google:

```
identify * |
    gawk '{split($3,sizes,"x"); print $1,sizes[1]/sizes[2]}' |
    sed 's/\[.\]//' | sort -gk 2
```

This is a output:

```
28.webp 0.698404
1.webp 0.699544
27.webp 0.706956
10.webp 0.707061
25.webp 0.707061
9.webp 0.707061
2.webp 0.707241
22.webp 1.41431
23.webp 1.41431
24.webp 1.41431
```

Then I made some adaptations to fit my need:

```
identify * |
    gawk '{split($3,sizes,"x"); print $1,sizes[1]/sizes[2]}' | 
    sed 's/\[.\]//' | sort -gk 2 |
    gawk '{print $1}' |
    mpv --no-resume-playback --really-quiet --playlist=-
```

It works, but isn't perfect. It can't deal with filename with space and `identify` is too slower than `exiftool` especially when handling WebP format, besides, `exiftool` has a `-r` option, so I want to use `exiftool` to get this output instead, but I don't know how to deal with the output of `exiftool -r -s -ImageSize`, anyone could help me?

Comment: [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input (the output if `identify *`, not the output of that piped to your existing awk+sed commands that don't do what you want) and the final expected output you want given that input. Obviously, if you want to start with `exiftool -r -s -ImageSize` output instead of `identify` output then show the output of that instead of the output of `identify *` as the sample input.

Comment: What if the image does not have Exif info?

Answer (score 3):

Using [exiftool](https://exiftool.org/) you could use
`exiftool -p '$filename ${ImageSize;m/(\d+)x(\d+)/;$_=$1/$2}' /path/to/files | sort -gk 2`

This will format the output the same as your example and I assume the same `sort` command will work with that.  If not, then the `sort` part would need editing.

Comment: Here's a version with tidier output and support for spaces in filenames: `exiftool -p '${ImageSize;m/(\d+)x(\d+)/;$_=$1/$2} $filename' /path/to/files | awk '{$1=sprintf("%.2f",$1)}1' | sort -k 1,2`

Answer (score 1):

Display aspect ratio and image filename without additional calculations with `identify`

```
identify -format '%f %[fx:w/h]\n' *.jpg | sort -n -k2,2
file1.jpg 1
file2.jpg 1.46789
file6.jpg 1.50282
file5.jpg 1.52
file7.jpg 1.77778
file3.jpg 1.90476
```

Regarding performance of `identify` vs `exiftool`, `identify` makes less calls but `exiftool` looks faster

```
strace -c identify -format '%f %[fx:w/h]\n' *.jpg 2>&1 | grep -E 'syscall|total'
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
100.00    0.001256                   867        43 total

strace -c exiftool -r -s -ImageSize *.jpg 2>&1 | grep -E 'syscall|total'
% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
100.00    0.000582                  1138       311 total
```

Comment: `identify *` is slower and `identify -format '%f %[fx:w/h]\n' *` is slowest, that's why I chose `exiftool` and any images has `ImageSize`info.